# How to find all files containing only hex zeroes

Tags: files, find

I am using 20.04.  I had some disk problems which I solved by using fsck. However, this left me with a configuration file that was the correct size but contained only hex '00' throughout instead of the correct config details. Now I would like to check every file on the disk to find any that contain only zeroes. There will be some legitimate files that match the criteria.
Thank you.

Comment: What's the difference between hex 0, binary 0 and decimal 0?

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like

```
find path/to/startdir/ -type f ! -empty -exec grep -zvL '^$' {} +
```

or (perhaps better, since it performs a non-empty *string* match)

```
find . -type f ! -empty -exec grep -zvFxL '' {} +
```

This matches (after excluding empty files) files that have at least one non-empty null-delimited sequence - if a file consists of nothing but null bytes, then every null-delimited "line" will be empty.